# I need to return an array of weekdays if there are two or more equal values in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The explanation is kinda hard but here is the official explanation:

> mostPopularDays: This function determines which day of the week had the most number of people visiting the pet store. If two or more days are tied for the highest amount of traffic, an array containing the days (in any order) should be returned. If the input is null or an empty array, the function should return null. The input is an array of Weekday objects, which are created using the prototype function defined toward the bottom of petstore.js. This function should return a string containing the name of the most popular day of the week if there is only one most popular day, and an array containing the names (as strings) of the most popular days if there are more than one that are most popular.

So the code I have right now is:

```
function mostPopularDays (week) {
  var name,
      dayInstance,
      highestTrafficYet = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < week.length; ++i) {
    dayInstance = week[i];
    traffic = dayInstance.traffic;

    if (highestTrafficYet < traffic) {
      name = dayInstance.name;
      highestTrafficYet = traffic;
    }
  }
  return name;
}
```

How do I return an array if there are multiple equal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments below for the explanation, but if you sort the values first, you can find the highest traffic day (or one of them). Then you use that traffic number to test the rest, which you can filter out all those that aren't as high
Finally, you can output a single name if there's only one highest day, or map the result to just the name property if there are more than one.

```js
let data = [{
  traffic: 4, name: 'mon'
}, {
  traffic: 2, name: 'weds'
}, {
  traffic: 4, name: 'tues'
}];

function mostPopularDays(week) {
  let sorted = week.sort((a, b) => b.traffic - a.traffic); // get the higehest traffic days at the top
  let highest = sorted[0].traffic // sample the highest value
  days = sorted.filter(a => a.traffic >= highest); // filter the days to only have the highest
  if (days.length === 1) return days[0].name // just one? return the name
  else return days.map(e => e.name) // more than one? map the array to be just the day names
}
console.log(mostPopularDays(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the greatest number of people that visited and then use `Array#filter` to find all days that had that many people.

```
function mostPopularDays (week) {
  if(!week?.length) return null;
  const max = Math.max(...week.map(x => x.traffic));
  const days = week.filter(x => x.traffic === max).map(x => x.name);
  return days.length === 1 ? days[0]: days;
}
```

Comment: great but uh SyntaxError: Unexpected token . was given

Comment: @MohammedAayanPathan On which line?

Comment: line 3 the ... part (there can be no es6 code)

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
function mostPopularDays(week) {
  var name,
    dayInstance,
    highestTrafficYet = -1,
    trafficIndexedDaysObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < week.length; ++i) {
    dayInstance = week[i];
    traffic = dayInstance.traffic;

    if (highestTrafficYet < traffic) {
      name = dayInstance.name;
      highestTrafficYet = traffic;

      // Clear previous hightest days
      trafficIndexedDaysObj = {};

      // Store highest Day in Array and put the Array in an Object with Traffic as key
      trafficIndexedDaysObj[traffic] = [name];
    } else if (highestTrafficYet == traffic && Array.isArray(trafficIndexedDaysObj[traffic])) {
      // If the same Traffic exists, append that Day to the already created Days Array
      trafficIndexedDaysObj[traffic].push(dayInstance.name);
    }
  }

  if (Object.keys(trafficIndexedDaysObj).length > 0) {
    // Return array of Days when the Highest Traffic occurred on more than one Days 
    var keys = Object.keys(trafficIndexedDaysObj);

    if (trafficIndexedDaysObj[keys[0]].length > 1) {
      return trafficIndexedDaysObj[keys[0]];
    }
  }

  return name;
}

mostPopularDays([{
  'traffic': 100,
  'name': 'Monday'
}, {
  'traffic': 64,
  'name': 'Tuesday'
}, {
  'traffic': 52,
  'name': 'Wednesday'
}, {
  'traffic': 100,
  'name': 'Thursday'
}, {
  'traffic': 100,
  'name': 'Friday'
}, {
  'traffic': 100,
  'name': 'Saturday'
}])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_tamil/ync47bjv/18/